# Mobile Site Usability

Tags: usability, usability-testing, mobile-web, usability-study

What are some of the tools to use for testing the mobile site UI and UX?

My company has a desktop site and now we have decided to build a mobile website.
We have tested our desktop site with services like trymyui.com to understand user's way of thinking while they browse through our site.

However trymyui does not test for mobile site. Are there any tools or services to test usability of mobile site?

Comment: I'd be surprised if other companies weren't offering remote user testing on mobile devices: the principle is the same, its just a different screen.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/ provides automated basic UX analysis for mobile along with performance analysis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I won't use remote testing for mobile apps, because:

- Hardware need to be good enough to handle simultaneously one consuming app (screen grabbing and video saving) and your test app.
- Streaming isn't possible or only in WiFi conditions.
- You need enough disk space / SD space.
- That narrows your testable smartphones down to premium phones with mostly huge screen resolutions.
- All screen recorder apps must have a rooted smartphone.
- You will get bad results due to lack of hardware performance or you might wonder if it's from your app or the performance.
- You won't see user's thumb or fat finger problems (like you see the mouse at desktop wandering around)

A nice setup I work with is:

- Mr.Tappy framework http://www.mrtappy.com/
- ION Action cam pluged upon it

You can give it to people and watch videos later. And ION Action cam can stream video over WiFi, so you can watch it live on your PC/Tablet/Smartphone without disturbing testers.

Answer (score 2):

personally i prefer guerrilla usability testing aka cafe testing, where you approach people in cafes (when they aren't busy) and offer them a coffee in exchange for their time.